# AngularJS | Sorting JSON based on geolocation (lat, long)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, geolocation

Trying to sort a JSON file based on device's geolocation.

JSON File:

```
jsonCallback(


        [  
           {  
              "codelocatie":"AL0008",
              "codecontainer":"GAL0008444",
              "gemeente":"Almelo",
              "straatnaam":"Bornerbroeksestraat",
              "omschrijving":"bij Aldi",
              "model":"BG 3000",
              "soort":"GLAS",
              "gps-x":"52.3497120",
              "gps-y":"6.66140500"
           },
           {  
              "codelocatie":"AL0010",
              "codecontainer":"GAL0010005",
              "gemeente":"Almelo",
              "straatnaam":"Bornsestraat 48",
              "omschrijving":"park.pl. Plusmarkt",
              "model":"OG 4000",
              "soort":"GLAS",
              "gps-x":"52.3512100",
              "gps-y":"6.66672100"
           },
           {  
              "codelocatie":"AL0010",
              "codecontainer":"KAL0010003",
              "gemeente":"Almelo",
              "straatnaam":"Bornsestraat 48",
              "omschrijving":"park.pl. Plusmarkt",
              "model":"OG 5000",
              "soort":"KVM",
              "gps-x":"52.3512200",
              "gps-y":"6.66672900"
           },
           {  
              "codelocatie":"AL0010",
              "codecontainer":"KAL0010004",
              "gemeente":"Almelo",
              "straatnaam":"Bornsestraat 48",
              "omschrijving":"park.pl. Plusmarkt",
              "model":"OG 5000",
              "soort":"KVM",
              "gps-x":"52.3512200",
              "gps-y":"6.66672900"
           }
    ]

   );
```

The device's geolocation I store in a div.

This is how i currently get the JSON data

```
.controller('afvalbakController' ,['$scope', '$http', 
    function afvalbakController($scope, $http) { 
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        url : 'http://www.lans.ink/TABLE_3.json?callback=?',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
         success: function(data) {
            $scope.contents = data;
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
    })
}])
```

It currently just grabs the first one, then the second etc.

I want it to sort by geolocation, so closest first but have had no luck so far.
Can this be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: Just curious, why you are not calculating the distance at your server end and then getting the result in callback ? also when you are injecting `$http` why you are using $.ajax ?

Comment: Well, the answer is actually quite simple. This is for a school project and I don't know how to. The reason I'm using $.ajax is because I need to get the JSON as jsonp otherwise I run into access-Control-Allow-Origin header problems.

Comment: You can still use `jsonp` with `$http`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Comment: I tried, but it didn't seem to work, so I want for the $.ajax option

Answer (score 1):

do loop on your locations array and check distance between each point to your geolocation point and sorted it. here is a function to check distance between 2 points.

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180;
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180;
    var theta = lon1-lon2;
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344; }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684; }
    return dist;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I be able to do the loop and then sort it based on that? I'm a real novice when it comes to this, but I'm eager to learn.

Comment: option 1: for loop of points array and save into new array all distances and then sort this array.
option 2 (better): sorting the distances array imdiatly, for loop on points array and then check each distance and push it to distances array to the right index